# Problema com formatação de hora ao usar o Moment.js e o Dialogflow

Tags: javascript, formatação, momentjs

Estou com um problema ao digitar algum horário no Dialogflow para meu chatbot. Sei que o sistema trabalha com AM e PM, mas tentei formatar a data com o Moment.js (segue o código abaixo), mas não está funcionando. Ao colocar um input de 9h, 10h, 11h ou 12h ele reconhece respectivamente como 21h, 22h, 23h e 00h. Alguma sugestão?

```
function consulta(agent) {
    let data = moment(agent.parameters.date).format('L');
    let tempo = moment(agent.parameters.time).tz('America/Recife').format('HH:mm');
    agent.add(`${data} às ${tempo}`);
}
```

Comment: Sugiro [edit] a pergunta e colocar o valor de `agent.parameters.time`, para os casos que funciona e que não funciona. Assim podemos saber melhor o que pode estar acontecendo (já que agora não dá pra saber se é uma string, um Date, em qual formato vem, etc)

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [documentação sobre formatação do Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), os *tokens* `HH` e `mm` formatam, respectivamente, para a hora em 24 horas (entre `00` e `23`) e o minuto (entre `00` e `59`).

Desse modo, se você quiser formatar, por exemplo, o horário 3 horas e 8 minutos PM, utilizando o padrão acima, você terá:

```
"HH:mm" → 15:08
```

Se você não quiser a formatação no modelo de 24 horas, precisará usar os *tokens* `hh` e `mm`, além do `A` – para indicar `AM` ou `PM`.

Assim, se você quiser formatar o mesmo horário de antes – 3 horas e 8 minutos PM – utilizando esse novo padrão, você terá:

```
"hh:mm A" → 03:08 PM
```

Então, basicamente:

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│  Tipo   │ Formato │          Exemplo           │
├─────────┼─────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ Período │ A       │ AM (ou) PM                 │
│ Período │ a       │ am (ou) pm                 │
│ Horas   │ HH      │ 01, 02, ... 12, 13, ... 23 │
│ Horas   │ hh      │ 01, 02, ... 12, 01, ... 11 │
└─────────┴─────────┴────────────────────────────┘
```

Novamente, para saber mais sobre esses formatos, consulte a [documentação de formatação](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).